# DataGrip fails to import CSV file with entries-count exceeding a specific threshold

Tags: csv, import, overflow, datagrip, mariadb-10.4

I have a MaridaDB table and importing a CSV file of 36,000 entries using the DataGrip "import" dialog box **succeeds** with no issues at all; but, when a single entry is added to the CSV file to have 36,001 entries, the import fails with the following *not-so-helpful* notice:

> Can't rollback changes with error records. Check connection and
> database settings and try again.

I'm using the latest version of DataGrip (v2022.3.2, build #DB-223.8214.62) with MariaDB (v10.4.24) and the latest stable version of DataGrip MariaDB Driver (v3.0.7). My table doesn't have any restrictions (like having a unique column, or whatever), and the issue is certainly not with the added entry (it's absolutely valid and all).

To me, it seems like some kind of "overflow" issue. So, how may I successfully import larger count of CSV entries using DataGrip?

---

<sub>*Interestingly, the same CSV file of 36,001 entries gets imported to the same table using **phpMyAdmin** with no problems at all. I've gone even further and successfully imported a CSV file of 100K+ entries using phpMyAdmin; but sadly, the small CSV file of 36,001 entries still doesn't get imported using DataGrip!*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Please open a support ticket:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=DBE

Attach the idea.log and activate the error log option from the Import window.

If you could additionally provide the csv file in question, that'd be great.